# Facebook mediation: We haven't received a bid request

Tags: flutter, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I have a Flutter app using Facebook mediation ads with Admob. This is working fine for Android but not for iOS.

All setup is looking fine in either Facebook or Admob:
[image]

but for iOS it says:

> ```
> We haven't received a bid request
> ```

[image]

Mediation group is also created in Admob and I'm using the ad IDs I created in Facebook.

Testing my app on simulator I get this message also:

> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s):
> com.google.DummyAdapter

This is been like that for weeks now.
Why is this happening only in iOS?

More info:
[image]